# Why is the returned value is none in this Python/MySQL search

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I have this little code

```
cquery = "SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE `Username` = (%s)"
cvalue = (usernameR,)
flash(cquery)
flash(cvalue)
x = c1.execute(cquery, cvalue)
flash(x)
```

**usernameR** is  a string variable I got it's value from a form

**x** supposed to be the number of rows or some value but it returns **none** I need it's value for one if.

I tested it with a value that is in the table in one row so thats not  the case the the value is not there or something. But if it's not there in that case the **x** should return 0 or something.

I cant work out what's the problem after several hours.

value of cvalue:

```
('Csabatron99',)
```

Edit for solution:

I needed to add the **rowcount** and **fetchall** to the code like this:

```
cquery = "SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE `Username` = (%s)"
cvalue = (usernameR,)
flash(cquery)
flash(cvalue)
c1.execute(cquery, cvalue)
c1.fetchall()
a = c1.rowcount
```

Comment: What is `flash()`?

Comment: `cursor.execute()` doesn't return anything unless you use the `multi=True` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.execute()` doesn't return anything in the normal case. If you use the `multi=True` argument, it returns an iterator used to get results from each of the multiple queries.

To get the number of rows returned by the query, use the `rowcount` attribute.

```
c1.execute(cquery, cvalue)
flash(c1.rowcount)
```

Comment: `flash()` is just an output to the webpage for errors and stuff I'm using it for debugging.
With `c1.rowcount` it's just output a 0 but I'm 100% sure that what I'm looking for are in the table.

Comment: Is `ID` the username column in the table?

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you execute the query by hand?

Comment: I tested it with the ID and the username too, of course both times with the coresponding values with my code but nothing. And when I tested the search in phpMyadmin I got the expected result yes result `"SELECT * FROM 'workers' WHERE 'Username' = 'Csabatron99' "` (its just a test username)

Comment: Make sure there's no extraneous whitespace in `usernameR`. `usernameR = usernameR.strip()`

Comment: used the code what you provided but nothing happened. if its help I edited the question a littlebit and I replaced the ID whit the Username what's inside the actual code now.

Comment: I answered the question about why `x == None`. That's a different problem.

Comment: For the rowcount I finally got an answer. I needed to add the `c1.fetchall()` before the `c1.rowcount` and after the `c1.execute`

Comment: If you use `resultlist = c1.fetchall()` you don't need `rowcount`, you can just use `len(resultlist)`